# how to copy an entry in a row to another row, but in the same column in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, set, field

this might sound like a trivial question but i've looked everywhere.
I have a table like this:

```
id   var1
1
2    19353
```

there is no entry for var1 where id =1 and I want to copy the entry for var1 from the other row to that location so that i have

```
id   var1
1    19353
2    19353
```

i've tried but was unsuccessful with:

```
update table set var1 = (select var1 from table where id=2) where id=1;
```

any advice?
thanks!

Comment: Why was this unsuccessful. Looks good to me! What does the table look like after you issue the `UPDATE`?

Comment: i got the error **ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause**

Comment: Ah! Try `update table set var1 = (select t2.var1 from table AS t2 where t2.id=2) where id=1;`

Comment: i seem to get the same error...

Comment: Even with everything aliased?

Comment: yup, the column i'm trying to apply it to is of type varchar(255) but this shouldn't really matter right? i did the alias it gave the same error unfortunately

Comment: i might have not deleted the extra where...

Comment: By the way, are you really using the table name `table`? **DON'T!** If you are, it needs to be escaped all over the place, or it will confuse the parser. I tested this on Postgres with a table called `t`; works.

Comment: no, i was just trying to simplify the question, but it's not called table - i did use the alias properly but it didn't work

Comment: i was just looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause, does that mean i would need a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL seems to have its own ideas about the syntax for multi-table update (a/k/a `UPDATE FROM`). Looks like the following is required. Except, I don't have MySQL to test on.

```
UPDATE t AS t1, t AS t2
SET t1.var1 = t2.var1
WHERE t1.id=1 AND t2.id=2;
```

EDIT: I have changed table name to `t`; we don't want a reserved word there.

Comment: where do i specify the table name?

Comment: oh in the place where you put t?